# Why do all security camera systems use ActiveX?

Tags: security, activex

Recently we purchased a new DVR for our security cameras and we have had several security systems before that. The web interface of all of them has used ActiveX to display the camera feeds.

Why is this? ActiveX seems so old and incompatible, and most users know it presents a security risk. Surely JavaScript or HTML5 or something can take its place now?

Comment: Possibly the [security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) site is more suited to this question?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have direct access to hardware. The browser needs something like ActiveX to communicate directly with the camera.

Comment: @Juhana So ActiveX allows the server to communicate with the actual hardware, as a C program might control a web-camera on an ordinary laptop?

Comment: This isn't about direct access to hardware - this is remotely accessing the DVR via a TCP connection. There is no reason the DVR hardware can supply the same data via HTTP in a HTML5 compatible video format that the browser can directly make use of.

Answer (score 1):

The firmware in camera was also very very old, they were designed decades ago but were proved to working well. And the manufacturers are working hard on trying to sell more products, reduce the cost but no incentive to upgrade the system.

Technically:
1) These security system usually use RTSP(Real-time Streaming Protocol) or some other self-defined protocol which the browser could not handle yet. So a plugin on browser side is required. We have tried Java Applet and Adobe Flash to take place of ActiveX, also they have lots of improvements on security and platform independence but still not solve the problem entirely,(Flash - iOS, JavaApplet - Security).

2) JS could not handle those protocol, HTML5 is lack of unified standards and browser support. We start study HTML5 years ago, hoping to simplify the whole system, but met a lot of problems, and things got more complicated since the rise of the mobile internet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess that pretty much explains it and it confirms what I was thinking. One of the key reasons then is that the security companies have found something that works securely so do not want to upgrade and run the risk of a security exploit?